# Laravel - How to Eagerload the relation when filtering with multiple condition

Tags: laravel

i have a problem to eagerload the relation data when filtering the data based oh what the users inputed. i often use with() to eagerload the relations, But in this case somehow its not working.

this is my code

```
public function fotoTrxSearch(Request $request){

    $transaction = Foto::orderByDesc('id'); 
    //i tried something like $transaction = Foto::with('mediaCategory','user')->orderByDesc('id'); but nor working

    if($request->filled('name')){
        $transaction->where('name', 'like', "%{$request->name}%");
    }
    if($request->filled('from') AND $request->filled('to')){
        $transaction->whereBetween('date', [$request->get('from'), $request->get('to')]);
    }
    if($request->filled('price')){
        $transaction->where('price','like', "%{$request->price}%");
    }
    if($request->filled('user_id')){
        $transaction->where('user_id',$request->user_id);
    }
    if($request->filled('media_id')){
        $transaction->where('media_id',$request->media_id);
    }
    if($request->filled('folder')){
        $transaction->where('folder','like', "%{$request->folder}%");
    }

    $transaction = new FotoCollection($transaction->paginate(150)->appends($request->query()));
    //also tried $transaction = new FotoCollection($transaction->with('mediaCategory','user')->paginate(150)->appends($request->query())); not working


    return Inertia::render('Foto/FotoList',[ 'fotos' => $transaction , 'user' => $user]);
   
}
```

i tried to do something like

```
$transaction = Foto::with('mediaCategory','user')->orderByDesc('id');
```

and

```
$transaction = new FotoCollection($transaction->with('mediaCategory','user')->paginate(150)->appends($request->query()));
```

**UPDATE**
this is my relations on model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->BelongsTo(User::class);
}
public function mediaCategory(){
    return $this->BelongsTo(MediaCategory::class,'media_id');
}
//media category model
public function foto(){
    return $this->BelongsTo(Foto::class);
}
    public function foto(){
    return $this->BelongsTo(Foto::class);
}
//user model
public function foto(){
    return $this->HasMany(Foto::class);
}
//collection
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
    ];
}
```

the data load as always but the relation data not showing up.
please help me to figure this problems
Thankyou in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The below code is not correct because you don't declare  $user and $mediaCategories before. You need to get mediaCategory and user in a loop instead of:

```
  Inertia::render('Foto/FotoList',[ 'fotos' => $transaction , 'user' => $user , 'mediaCategories' => $mediaCategories]);
```

Comment: not working , still not showed up

Comment: Can you show your code in FotoCollection class and the relationship in your model?

Comment: i already added the model relations

Comment: i think my relations is working because in show method its work properly , but in the fotoTrxSearch not working as expected

Comment: Can you show me the code of FotoCollection class and how you get mediaCategory and user, too?

Comment: i updated it already

Comment: Well, I think the problem is your collection. Try dd($transaction->paginate(150)) to see whether the data contain mediaCategory and user relationship or not